# WHM with Centos : /etc/sudoers ALL=(ALL) - when switching to root still asks for root password

Tags: ssh, cpanel, centos6, ssh-keys, whm

I'm trying to figure out why after adding:

```
newsshadmin    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

to the `/etc/sudoers` file on Centos I'm still asked for root password when trying to switch to root i.e.:

```
ssh newsshadmin@ip_address
su - root
```

this triggers the password prompt.

Answer (score 1):

To use sudoes is necessary to execute the sudo command before any other commands like that **sudo su - root**.

Another problem is the line you used to allow **su** command without password, this is the correct entry:

```
newsshadmin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: NOPASSWD: ALL
```